# Vue router trying to use params as the name to match route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to use params in my routes and created the below routes.

```
export const ConsumerRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/' + import.meta.env.VITE_MODULE_ADMIN_NAME + '/consumers',
    meta: { 
      requiresAuth: true,
      adminLayout: true,
      module: 'admin',
      icon: UserCircleIcon,
      nav: 'Consumers'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Consumers',
        component: () => import('../../views/admin/Consumer.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        name: 'Consumer Details',
        component: () => import('../../views/admin/ConsumerDetails.vue'),
      }
    ],
  },

  // {
  //   path: '/' + import.meta.env.VITE_MODULE_ADMIN_NAME + '/consumers/:id',
  //   meta: { 
  //     requiresAuth: true,
  //     adminLayout: true,
  //     module: 'admin',
  //     excludeFromNav: true
  //   },
  //   children: [
  //     {
  //       path: '',
  //       name: 'Consumer Details',
  //       component: () => import('../../views/admin/ConsumerDetails.vue'),
  //     }
  //   ]
  // }
];
```

I can navigate to consumers but as soon as I put /1 in the url I get this error

```
vue-router.mjs:810 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No match for
 {"name":"1","params":{}}
```

But if I console.log my to route in an afterEach function I get this
[route object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypzrg.png)

So it knows which route I am trying to go to but for some reason it is using the '1' to trying and find a route named '1'. If I change the name of my route to 1 it loads fine.

I have tried splitting my routes from being children and being separate routes but it doesn't change anything

---

Solved it and it was unrelated to my defined routes

Comment: You are mission in your `:id` path the `'/:id'` i believe, otherwise it will do a `/consumers:id`

Comment: I've tried putting / in different places and it makes no difference where they are

Comment: What version of vue-router you are working with ?

Comment: I'm using ver. 4.1

Comment: Can you provide pls your App.vue and the main.(js|ts) and your `views/admin/ConsumerDetails.vue` pls?  :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to Vue Router trying to match a route by its name rather than its path.

You're trying to navigate to /consumers/1, intending "1" to be a route parameter (:id). But Vue Router is interpreting "1" as a route name, hence the error message you're seeing.

Ensure that you're navigating using route paths, not route names. In your afterEach hook, use:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  router.push(to.path);
});
```

And when manually navigating, use the path ('/consumers/1'), not the name. If you're still having issues, it might be due to another part of your code.

Here's how you might navigate to a route by its name:

```
router.push({ name: 'Consumer Details', params: { id: 1 } })
```

And, here's how you might navigate to a route by its path:

```
router.push('/consumers/1')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. I've tried adding router.push(to.path); to my afterEach and it just makes my site hang and it looks like it's in a loop of going to the url

Comment: Dear jordan, as I understand it correctly, your router part is ok. on the handler (btn or somewhere else) you need to push your new route correctly. remove the afterEach, and use router.push('consumers/1') I have provided to you.

Comment: Yeah but it happens when I type the URL. No buttons involved

Answer (score -2):

```
Demo 

 <li v-for="article in articles" @click="getDescribe(article.id)">

scheme 1
      {
       path: '/describe/:id',
       name: 'Describe',
       component: Describe
      }

      getDescribe(id) {
        this.$router.push({
          path: `/describe/${id}`,
      })

    this.$route.params.id

scheme 2

  {
     path: '/describe',
     name: 'Describe',
     component: Describe
   }

   this.$router.push({
          name: 'Describe',
          params: {
            id: id
          }
   })

   this.$route.params.id


scheme 3
  
       this.$router.push({
          path: '/describe',
          query: {
            id: id
          }
        })

   {
     path: '/describe',
     name: 'Describe',
     component: Describe
   }
   
this.$route.query.id
```